# Running a function a set amount of times in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some JQuery that is putting divs randomly on a page. However, currently, it does it infinitely.

How can I get it do run for a set amount of time then stop?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  makeDiv();

var  count = 1;
  function makeDiv() {
    
    count ++;
    while (count < 50){
      var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
      var divsize = 100;
      var posx = (Math.random() * ($('body').width() - divsize)).toFixed();
      var posy = (Math.random() * ($('body').height() - divsize)).toFixed();
      $newdiv = $("<div class='exploding'></div>").css({
        'left': posx + 'px',
        'top': posy + 'px'
      });
      $newdiv.appendTo('body').delay(2000).fadeIn(100, function () {
        //$(this).remove();
        makeDiv();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body, html {
    width: 960;
    height: 100%;
}
div.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
div.exploding {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the `count` with inside the `makeDiv` instead of global .And add `count++` inside the end of the while loop . Dont use same `makeDiv()` inside the while.they while loop is overload

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  makeDiv();


  function makeDiv() {
    var  count = 1;
  
    while (count < 50){
      var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
      var divsize = 100;
      var posx = (Math.random() * ($('body').width() - divsize)).toFixed();
      var posy = (Math.random() * ($('body').height() - divsize)).toFixed();
      $newdiv = $("<div class='exploding'></div>").css({
        'left': posx + 'px',
        'top': posy + 'px'
      });
      $newdiv.appendTo('body').delay(2000).fadeIn(100, function () {
        $(this).remove();
      //  makeDiv();
      });
        count ++;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body, html {
    width: 960;
    height: 100%;
}
div.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
div.exploding {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`count++;` has to be inside of the while loop